# Linking same Python/Django app to Heroku repository and Github Repo

Tags: git, heroku, pycharm

I am working on a Django/python project in the Pycharm IDE

I've already followed the instructions here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django#store-your-app-in-git to link the local folder to a heroku server and could deploy it to a server and check that everything works fine

In Pycharm there is an option : VCS -->Import into Version Control -->Share project on Github

Will this create a separate .git folder in my project folder for Github purposes, and the heroku git commits would be unaffected?

Thanks

Comment: There's no way it'll create a separate .git folder -- you can't have two directories with the same name. I am guessing it will detect you already have a git repository, and just add a new remote for github (http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes).

Answer (score 0):

> Will this create a separate `.git` folder in my project folder for Github purposes, and the heroku git commits would be unaffected?

No, it can create the GitHub repo for you though: the [share project on github dialog](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/share-project-on-github-dialog.html) includes a "`Share`" button you can click to have PyCharm initiate repository creation and afterwards upload the project sources to the new repository.

You can check the name of the remote created to reference the GitHub repo (`git remote -v`), but since the [Heroku Getting Started guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django#store-your-app-in-git) adds a remote named "heroku", IDEA can add a remote named origin (the default name) without creating any conflict.
Note that you [cannot add a new remote from IDEA itself](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-87099).